# Twilio - Register Campaign Use Case for A2P 10DLC - Messaging Services

Tags: twilio, sms, messaging

We have 560 different Messaging Services for our customers in Twilio. We are trying to register *one* of these for an A2P 10DLC Campaign Use Case so that we can do some discovery and perhaps build a PoC.

We have:

- Created our business profile in TrustHub
- Registered our US A2P brand
- Attempted to "Setup Messaging Service" by checking "Use an existing Messaging Service"

Only the first 20 Messaging Services are shown. There is no way to paginate, filter, or sort. I can't find anything about Campaigns in the API documentation or I would do this with the SDK or Postman.

I am still waiting on a response to my support ticket and emails to our account representative. Two million SMS messages a month seems like we would be eligible for a response in under a week, but we're currently blocked.

Is there anyone who has encountered this problem and can offer some suggestions while we wait to hear back? Thank you for any assistance.

[Campaign Registration Console Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPaLC.png)

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio. Would love to help here, though I don't think we'll be able to solve this on Stack Overflow. Can you drop me an email at philnash at twilio dot com with your Account SID and ticket number and I'll see what I can do to get this sorted.